# SELECT_EXTENDED=COVER option in gracenote API does not return artwork

Tags: c#, xml, gracenote

The gracenote [samples page](https://developer.gracenote.com/sites/default/files/web/html/index.html#Music%20Web%20API/Common%20Queries.html#_Toc344907235) states it's possible to receive data of multiple albums including one albumart url (COVER_SIZE is disregarded) when option `SELECT_EXTENDED=COVER` is provided.

My xml request looks like

```
<QUERIES>
<AUTH>
    <CLIENT>xxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</CLIENT>
    <USER>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</USER>
</AUTH>
<LANG>ger</LANG>
<COUNTRY>deu</COUNTRY>
<QUERY CMD="ALBUM_SEARCH">
    <TEXT TYPE="ARTIST">The Beatles</TEXT>
    <TEXT TYPE="ALBUM_TITLE">Help</TEXT>
    <RANGE>
        <START>1</START>
        <END>20</END>
    </RANGE>
    <OPTION>
        <PARAMETER>SELECT_EXTENDED</PARAMETER>
        <VALUE>COVER</VALUE>
    </OPTION>
</QUERY>
```

```

I played with the range to receive data of every album but none contained an url.
I switched to the C# API and wrote a little programme

```
ParkSquare.Gracenote.GracenoteClient c = new ParkSquare.Gracenote.GracenoteClient("xxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
ParkSquare.Gracenote.AlbumSearcher s=new ParkSquare.Gracenote.AlbumSearcher(c);

ParkSquare.Gracenote.SearchCriteria cr=new ParkSquare.Gracenote.SearchCriteria();
cr.AlbumTitle = "help";
cr.Artist = "the beatles";
cr.SearchOptions = ParkSquare.Gracenote.SearchOptions.Cover;
cr.SearchMode = ParkSquare.Gracenote.SearchMode.Default;

for (var ilauf = 0; ilauf < 5; ilauf++)
{
    cr.Range = new ParkSquare.Gracenote.Range((ilauf * 20) + 1, (ilauf+1) * 20 );
    ParkSquare.Gracenote.SearchResult sr = s.Search(cr);
    foreach(var a in sr.Albums)  {
        Console.WriteLine( string.Format("{0} {1}",a.Title, a.Artwork.Count()) );
    }
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

It shows no albumart with any album.
Is there an error? Am I missing something? Was the API changed and the function is not supported any longer?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. Surprisingly, searching for covers with MODE=SEARCH_BEST_COVER returns artworks (of course there is one big disadvantage: result list contains only one album).